# Filtering column based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple columns. I want the sheet to be filtered based on a row called 'Timing' And the value I want to filter for is called 'C10'. What is the code to write that will filter the Timing column for C10?

I tried

```
df_filtered=df[df['Timing] == 'C10'
```

The code did not work

Comment: You have a typo? `df[df['Timing'] == 'C10']` (missing ending `]`)

Comment: Sorry, yes I have it as you posted and it does not work.

Comment: Update your post with the output of `print(df.head())` please

Comment: There's another typo: `'Timing` is missing a closing single-quote.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input (enough data to demonstrate the issue), expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

**If you have no typo**, try to remove leading and trailing whitespace on your column first:

```
df_filtered = df[df['Timing'].str.strip() == 'C10']
```